# How to Evaluate code of another ruby file?

Tags: ruby

Here  have two ruby files, how to open file and evaluate code1.rb in code2.rb

- code1.rb

```
a = 10
b = 15
c = a+b
puts "c = #{c}"
```

- code2.rb

```
a= 10
e = c*5+a
puts "e = #{e}"
```

Expected output :

```
c = 25
e = 135
```

Comment: First,make up your mind which meachanism you want to use to pass data into code2.rb, because this will dictate, how to glue the two programs together. You could pass the data on the argument list (`ARGV` in Ruby), you can pass it via the environment (`ENV`), you can pass it over a pipe into `STDIN`, or you can pass the value via a file.

Comment: Can you put an examples for how to pass it over a pipe into STDIN, or you can pass the value via a file.

Comment: There are two different approaches, and I suggest that you post on [so] two questions about it. In particular, the file version could lead to a discussion with various proposals. Piping between programms X and Y is simply done in the shell (bash, zsh, ...)  by writing  `X|Y`. `X` writes the data to stdout and `Y` reads the data from stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Kernel#eval`](https://rubyapi.org/3.0/o/kernel#method-i-eval) in order to achieve what you want.

but in `code1.rb` you will need to remove `puts`, or place it before, as `puts` returns nil.
So use this changes

`code1.rb`

```rb
a = 10
b = 15
c = a+b
puts "c = #{c}"
c
```

`code2.rb`

```rb
code1 = File.open('code1.rb', 'r').read
c = eval(code1)

a = 10
e = c*5+a
puts "e = #{e}"
```

`c = eval(code1)` This magic line will use return value of your `code1.rb` file and then we can use it in `code2.rb`

Or another alternative you can allow your local variables to be overwritten by `eval` method, but in that case you need to define them in your `code2.rb`. Consider this

`code2.rb`

```rb
a,b,c = [0, 0, 0]

code1 = File.open('code1.rb', 'r').read
eval(code1)

a = 10
e = c*5+a
puts "e = #{e}"
```

That works due to local variables scope and evaluation. Both variants are working solutions